# Get element height when style = auto or 100%?

Tags: javascript, styles, element

Just as the questions asks how may I get the exact px height or width of an element when that element has style="width:100%; height:auto;" for example.

I may NOT nest it inside a div and get the height/width via so!

I'm guessing javascript can help out here.

EDIT: I am using this:

```
var collectNodes = document.getElementById('fade').children;

collectNodes[y].height() // ??
```

The following code provides me with the string "auto":

```
collectNodes[0].style.height;
```

EDIT2: This is my code.

```
<div id="divId">
    <img class="node" src="somePic0.png" style="z-index:10; opacity:0;"/>
    <img class="node" src="somePic1.png" style="z-index:9; opacity:0;"/>
    <img class="node" src="somePic2.png" style="z-index:8; opacity:1;"/> 
    <img class="node" src="somePic3.png" style="z-index:7; opacity:1;"/>
    <img class="node" src="somePic4.png" style="z-index:6; opacity:1;"/>
</div>

<script>
    var collectNodes = document.getElementById('divId').children; 
    var y = 0;
    for ( var x = 0; x < collectNodes.length; x++ ) {
        if ( collectNodes[x].style.opacity !== "" && !y ) {
            y = x;
        }
    }

    alert(collectNodes[y].height); // This alerts the string "auto" and not pixel height
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using jquery or another library or should it be in plain javascript?

Comment: Whichever one :) I Prefer jQuery, but javascript would work just aswell!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do it with pure javascript like this :

**Javascript**

```
var divHeight;
var obj = document.getElementById('id_element');

if(obj.offsetHeight) {
    divHeight=obj.offsetHeight;

} else if(obj.style.pixelHeight) {
    divHeight=obj.style.pixelHeight;

}
```

With jQuery library it's easier :

**JQuery**

```
var height = $('#element').height();
```

**Edit**

Now with many elements within a container :

**Html**

```
<div id="divId">
    <img class="node" src="path/to/pic" style="z-index:10; opacity:0;"/>
    <img class="node" src="path/to/pic" style="z-index:9; opacity:0;"/>
    <img class="node" src="path/to/pic" style="z-index:8; opacity:1;"/> 
    <img class="node" src="path/to/pic" style="z-index:7; opacity:1;"/>
    <img class="node" src="path/to/pic" style="z-index:6; opacity:1;"/>
</div>
```

I changed your opacity to visibility for compatibility purposes. Don't use display:none; or the height parsing will fail ;).

**JQuery**

```
$("#divId img").each(function(index, picture) {
   var height = $(picture).height();
   //Do everything you want with the height from the image now
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/X7vGR/4/) to see it working.

Comment: Updated my question and posted some javascript!

Comment: With jQuery you could use [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to parse every element in a container, may I have some html from your code to help you a bit more ?

Comment: Works great excpt that I need it be be as opacity due to the plugin I'm using :( I have the "collectNodes[y]" because it cycles through all the images and selects the one I wish to get the height from! But the code "collectNodes[y].height" only returns "auto"!

Comment: My code works with opacity too, i'm editing ;) What is the condition for your picture ? class, id, data attribute ?

Comment: I figured it out:     $("#fade img").each(function(index, picture) {
     if ($(picture).css("opacity") == 1 && done==0) {
      done=1;
      imageHeight = $(picture).height();
      imageWidth = $(picture).width();
     }       
    }); - Thank you :D