# Get actual height of object whose set to "auto"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This seems like quite a rudimentary issue, but no matter how I phrase it, I can't seem to find anyone who's got a solution for me.

I have an image that's set size to fit my layout and to retain its aspect ratio, like so:

```
img{
   width:50%;
   height:auto;
}
```

Since I don't know how high the image is, I have to calculate another element's position using the real height of the image (The size that it's been resized to through auto).

```
$("img").height();
```

This returns 0 whenever it's set to auto, however. 
What am I missing? Or how can I find the current height of an image set to auto :)?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get height of div with no height set in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592575/get-height-of-div-with-no-height-set-in-css)

Comment: @nicael Doesn't look like it, unfortunately :(

Comment: I don't see what the problem is? https://jsfiddle.net/XL2000/fkwpdd67/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get element height when style = auto or 100%?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276240/get-element-height-when-style-auto-or-100)

Comment: @Midas try getting the height on resize then :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In vanilla JavaScript:

```
element.offsetHeight;
```

To get correct value, make sure your image is **already loaded**. For this, either use the `load` event of `window`, or [preload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images#Creating_an_image_from_scratch) your image via JS. Do **not** use the `DOMContentLoaded` event of `document` or `ready` in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using the "[document ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)" event while you should be using the [`load` event](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/). You cannot retreive the dimensions of an image before it has been rendered in the browser.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        console.log('Height: ' + $('img').height());
    }).resize();
});
```

```css
img {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" height="200" width="200">
```

Comment: Not quite it. I'm looking for the resized height - not the original one.

Comment: @user3307017 Yes it is. The original height of the image in this example is 200px.

Comment: Try opening your snippet in full screen. Even though it's almost 2000px high, it still says 250~

Comment: @user3307017 I didn't handle window resize in this example. It shows the image size on load only.. Answer updated

Answer (score 1):

i think this would be helpful:

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("selector")).height;
```

It returns a string with the real height in px.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

```js
$(function () {

  // in jQuery you can use: 
  var h = $("img").height();
  console.log('$("img").height() is: ' + h);
  console.log('$("img").css("height") is: ' + $("img").css("height"));
  

  // in javascript, with the unit measure:
  // This form corresponds to the second jQuery method
  var elem = document.querySelectorAll('img')[0];
  var h1 = window.getComputedStyle(elem).height;
  console.log('window.getComputedStyle(elem).height is: ' + h1);
});
```

```css
img{
  width:50%;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://www.google.it/logos/doodles/2016/karl-landsteiners-148th-birthday-5693101206142976-res.png">
```